# Computer not connecting to wireless getting 169.254.x.x address

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ip

I have a computer trying to connect wirelessly to my network. All the other computers behind this router have a 192.168.1.x address, this computer is getting a 169.254.x.x address. I know that this is symbolic of a failure, but I have been completely unsuccessful in resolving this on my side.

Does someone have any standard troubleshooting steps I can employ when this comes up?

I've been trying ipconfig /release ... /flushdns ... /renew  and checking to make sure that DHCP is enabled and that the computer is set to pull it's IP via dhcp.

Windows 7 is the OS in question.

Comment: Are you able to ping 192.168.1.1 if you cannot then you are not connected to the same network.

Comment: Is your DHCP scope large enough, i.e. the DHCP server did not run out of IPs to hand out? Is your subnet mask large enough? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255999

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is WEP/WPA/WPA2 security enabled make sure you are entering the correct password.
2. Make sure on the wireless router that it does not require there to be a reservation to obtain an IP address.  This is typically done with a MAC address reservation.
3. Ensure the drivers for your wireless card on the computer are up to date.